distance meter tracker gps
For a couple of weeks I'm trying to build a simple taxi meter like app. Which has to do few simple thing after reach first 5km xx$ is added and then for each 1km xx$ is added. However I cannot find right way to make meeter tracker to work accurate.
What I have tried so far is using geolocation with haversine formula, google maps geometry, tried with react native but so far I cannot manage to make the distance tracker to work accurate. I keeps adding meters while in pace and most of the time the traveled distance is far from real.
So my question is: can someone that has experience already with this help me? Which direction to go(something specific to concentrate), what will the best approach, JS, some framework, swift etc. My initial idea was to build a PWA but I'm getting nowhere so far.
Google API is not added on purpose here. I do have them on my project
<script>
    let map;
    let currentPositionMarker;
    let previousPosition = null;
    let totalDistance = 0;
    const distanceThreshold = 20; // 20 meters threshold
    const minAccuracy = 30; // Minimum accuracy to consider valid position

    function initMap() {
        // Initialize the map centered on a default location
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 }, // San Francisco
            zoom: 13
        });

        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
                const accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

                if (accuracy > minAccuracy) {
                    // Ignore positions with poor accuracy
                    console.warn(`Ignoring position with poor accuracy: ${accuracy} meters`);
                    return;
                }

                const pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                // If there's no marker, create one
                if (!currentPositionMarker) {
                    currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pos,
                        map: map,
                        title: "Current Position"
                    });
                    map.setCenter(pos);
                } else {
                    currentPositionMarker.setPosition(pos);
                }

                // Calculate the distance if there's a previous position
                if (previousPosition) {
                    const previousLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(previousPosition.lat, previousPosition.lng);
                    const currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);
                    const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(previousLatLng, currentLatLng);

                    // Only add to total distance if it's above the threshold
                    if (distance > distanceThreshold) {
                        totalDistance += distance;
                    }
                }

                // Update the previous position
                previousPosition = pos;

                // Display the total distance
                document.getElementById('output').innerText = `Total Distance: ${totalDistance.toFixed(2)} meters`;
            }, () => {
                handleLocationError(true, map.getCenter());
            }, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                maximumAge: 10000, // Maximum age of cached position
                timeout: 5000 // Timeout for obtaining position
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, map.getCenter());
        }
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, pos) {
        alert(browserHasGeolocation ?
              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
    }
</script>


This question is probably too broad to get a helpful response. If you have a piece of code that is not working then people can give feedback though.

I work at a company that operates in the field of tracking software, where we use hardware embedded in vehicles to obtain accurate location coordinates. for the map we use the open source library leaflet.
